# iBeacon send notification for multiple beacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ibeacon

### Scenario

I have 3 merchants in a same street. Each merchant hold a beacon. I want end users to get notify once they go near *(`CLProximityNear`)*.

### Source code

**AppDelegate.m**

```
self.iBeaconManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.iBeaconManager.delegate = self;

NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];

CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID identifier:@"BeaconIdentifier"];
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

[self.iBeaconManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

Delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self.iBeaconManager requestStateForRegion:region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    switch (state) {
        case CLRegionStateInside: {
            [self.iBeaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

            notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are inside region %@", region.identifier];
            break;
        }

        case CLRegionStateOutside:
            notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are outside region %@", region.identifier];
        case CLRegionStateUnknown:
        default:
            NSLog(@"Region unknown");
    }

    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    if ([beacons count] > 0) {
        for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {

            NSMutableString *logText = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Beacon: major: %d minor: %d Distance: %f is", [beacon.major intValue], [beacon.minor intValue], beacon.accuracy];

            switch (beacon.proximity) {
                case CLProximityImmediate: // 0 - 20cm
                    [logText appendString:@" IMMEDIATE"];

                    break;

                case CLProximityNear: // 20cm - 2m
                    [logText appendString:@" NEAR"];

                    break;

                case CLProximityFar: // 2m - 70m
                    [logText appendString:@" FAR"];
                    break;

                default:
                    [logText appendString:@" UNKNOWN"];
                    break;
            }
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.alertBody = logText;
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

I will get unlimited notifications when I go close to the beacon

### Questions

I want those end users to get ONLY ONE notification when they go near.

e.g. **Hi, welcome to Shop A, we offer a great discount only for today**

Then when they go far, notify again **Thank you for visiting. Have a nice day**

Should I save the current state/proximity for that particular merchant *(beacon)* to `NSUserDefaults`? Actually I have try that

CLProximity currentProximity = ... // get proximity from a particular beacon saved in NSUserDefaults

```
switch (beacon.proximity) {
    case CLProximityImmediate: // 0 - 20cm
        [logText appendString:@" IMMEDIATE"];
        // if 1 second ago is Immediate, now still immediate
        if (currentProximity == CLProximityImmediate) continue;
        currentProximity = CLProximityImmediate;

        break;
    ...
}
```

After modified the code above, I get no notification when I press the home button *(app running in background)*

**Edit**

I think the problem is when the app running on background, `USUserDefaults` not actually works. I want to keep proximity state for every beacon even when the app is not running at all.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need do some logic here.

You should set flag for all the iBeacons. when a perticular iBeacons comes to near you should set flag that this iBeacons is near. **CLProximityNear**

Flag will be off when it goes to far **CLProximityFar**.

So you need to do the below step.

1. Set flag for all iBeacons to when it comes to near (Show notiication).
2. flag off when to goes far.

Make sure for the all iBeacons you need to do manage seperate flags

Comment: I tried to keep `CLProximity` for all beacons, but once I add `if (currentProximity == CLProximityImmediate) continue;`, it become no notification at all when the app running on background. it works only if the app is running on foreground

Comment: Sunny's solution is good so long as the app is in the foreground.  But as Yatheesha mentions, ranging will not work in the background for more than 5 secs after region entry.  Unfortunately this use case cannot work at all in the background because a user typically enters the region when far, and not enough background ranging time is available to become near.  Since most users will not have the app in the foreground, I would rethink this.

Comment: @davidgyoung are you sure ranging will not work in the background? beacause I have tested in the ios 7.1 in the background i had managed this.

Comment: @SunnyShah take a look at this link http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

Comment: @davidgyoung actually `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` works even the app not running. This morning when I came into office, I suddenly receive tons of notifications, and my app is not even in background

Comment: @Yatheesha take a look at this http://9to5mac.com/2014/03/11/ios-7-1-introduces-big-improvements-for-ibeacons-devs-weigh-in/

Comment: @JsLim i have faced the same problem that in your question, just try above this i think it will work for you

Comment: @SunnyShah perhaps, I can only push notification on enter/exit region. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Understand that it will work in the background, but only for about 5 seconds after your app is awakened into the background by an event.  These events can include beacon region entry/exit, receiving a push notification, illuminating the display, etc.  Each event requires a different setup to get it.

Comment: Ya you're right, it only last about 5 seconds. seems there are certain limitation on this technology. hopefully it has improvement in future

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24503395/2752948) for a similar question that may be of some use to you.

Basically, Apple does not want you ranging in the background, so that rules out any proximity reading that you can do. Of course that doesn't mean you can't do it, but should you?

One solution you can employ for restricting notifications is to keep track of the number of app badges.

```
BOOL isNoAppBadges = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                      applicationIconBadgeNumber] == 0);
BOOL isApplicationInBackground = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                      applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground);
```

Then

```
        if (isNoAppBadges &&
            isApplicationInBackground)
        {
            // Red badge that appears over the app icon
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];

            UILocalNotification *notification = [
                                    [UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            notification.alertBody = @"Your notification text";

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
        }
```

This logic has gone in:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state
          forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

It probably does not make a whole lot of sense to present notifications when the app is in the foreground, but for the sake of keeping the answer on topic, you could use the above logic in:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
           inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

And implement the same switch statement you've done in your example.